# Identificar se um determinado programa é o foco pelo C#

Tags: c#

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação, que irá inserir dados em outro programa (usando sendkeys, etc).

Para isso preciso saber se o programa é o que está em foco.

**Por exemplo**: A aplicação abrir o internet explorer, e navegar em um site fazendo inserções nos elementos do mesmo.

Então como eu faria para saber se o Internet Explorer é o programa que esta com o Foco?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Diego, para cumprir tal tarefa você precisará interagir com a API do Sistema Operacional, neste caso o Windows.

Quando você inicia uma nova instância do Internet Explorer você precisará obter o handler (identificador) do IE no Windows. Esta informação é obtida buscando pelo hWnd.

Feito isso você deve chamar a função GetActiveWindow da user32.dll para verificar se o hWnd obtido pela função é o mesmo que do IE que você já obteve. Caso seja o mesmo o IE é a janela ativa.

Segue código para exemplificar o que disse acima:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;

namespace ManipulaApp
{
    class Program
    {        
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var ie = Process.Start("iexplore.exe");

            while (true)
            {
                IntPtr hWnd = GetForegroundWindow();

                if (hWnd == ie.MainWindowHandle)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("IE ativo.");
                }

                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Obs.: Ainda que haja outro IE aberto somente o que foi aberto pela sua aplicação será identificado desta forma.

Espero ter conseguido te auxiliar.

Comment: caso ele não seja a janela ativa, tem como eu trazer-la para frente?

Comment: Sim, a API do Windows permite manipular as janelas quase completamente através do hWnd. A função adequada para deixar uma janela em foco através do handler é "SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd)". Você deve incluí-la da mesma forma que eu coloquei GetForegroundWindow no código de exemplo.